# Why can't I mine in more than one pool at the same time in pool mining?

Tags: bitcoin, pool, sha, mining, stratum

Why can't I mine in more than one pool at the same time in pool mining?

I thought I could send one share to more than one pool if the difficulty was the same.

It will be possible to increase my reward.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

When you mine in a pool, you must try to mine blocks that reward the members of that pool. That's what it means to mine in a pool.

An attempt to mine a block must be an attempt to mine some particular block. If you're attempting to mine a block that pays rewards to the members of pool A, you aren't attempting to mine a block that pays rewards to the members of pool B.

> Why can't I mine in more than one pool at the same time in pool mining?

Because no two pools ever try to mine the same block. To mine in a pool, you must be trying to mine the block that pool wishes to mine.

> I thought I could send one share to more than one pool if the difficulty was the same.

Nope. If you aren't actually trying to produce the blocks that a pool wants to mine, you are aren't entitled to shares.

> It will be possible to increase my reward.

No, it won't. Pool A won't reward you with shares for trying to mine blocks that pay to pool B's members. Why would they? And Pool B will only pay you for trying to mine blocks that pay to their members. Why would they pay you to mine any other blocks?

Answer (score -2):

You surely can do mining in more than one pool at the same time, but your hashrate don't speedup. Because mining pools use different methodologies to assign work to miners. Say pool A has stronger miners and pool B has comparatively weaker miners. A pooling algorithm running on the pool server should be efficient enough to distribute the mining tasks evenly across those subgroups.

Your miner device can only solve one question which distributed by PoolA or PoolB. Though the difficulty is same, the mining tasks from PoolA and PoolB are different.

You can checkout [bitcon stratum mining protocol](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Stratum_mining_protocol) for more information.